# Cannot get CountIf incorporated into array properly

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, count, countif

I want to place an array in a header to fill the column with a forumla when a row is not empty.

I use the below to pull information from a particular cell and it works great.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(G:G)=1,"Delivery Method",
if(REGEXMATCH(G:G,"QAS"),"QAS",if(REGEXMATCH(G:G,"Group"),"GIB",""))))
```

However I need to create a unique identifier for the email address.

I want to do this by using

```
=C2&countif(C2:C$3,C2)
```

This basically adds a numeric counter if the email shows more than once, eg. test@gmail.com1, test@gmail.com2

I can't figure out how to incorporate the array with it in google sheets. The below doesn't work fully. Thoughts? It doesn't increment the count, only shows the total count in the range per email.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(C:C)=1,"Email ID",C:C&countif(C:C ,C:C)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Email ID"; C2:C&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C))})
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Email ID"; IF(C2:C="",,
 C2:C&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C)))})
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Trying to add an if to show blank if there is no value in C but stuck again.

Comment: @Mark answer updated

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using C2:C and use C:C or something that doesn't specifically reference an exact cell? The worksheet I'm using is linked to a google form. If I delete all entry rows but the headers and a google form entry is completed and inserted, the formula adjusts to C3:C. However as soon as there is 1 entry and I adjust the array back to C2, all other entries are fine and the array doesn't update anymore. Thoughts?

Comment: @Mark you can try to freeze it... change C2:C to INDIRECT("C2:C")